# Spam, captcha - limit Contact Us page to country where you're doing business

Tags: seo, wordpress, spam-prevention

I do business only in the USA, however my content is relevant in just about any region of the world.  I routinely get spam via my Contact Us page, almost all of which comes from outside of the US.  While I do have Captcha enabled, it obviously isn't perfect, especially when spammers hire cheap labor to manually do their work.

So, this made me wonder, what if I limited my Contact Us page to just users coming from the USA?  The rest of my site would still be available.

I'm guessing I could do this with .htaccess, but would this hurt my SEO?

Comment: Why not just handle the display of the contact form or its submission differently rather than blocking it to non-US people?

Comment: @davidgo, are you thinking of filtering the display of the form using server side code or something different?

Comment: Yes - Im thinking along the lines of "look up region of requestors IP and decide whether or not to dosplay contect form on page".

Comment: @davidgo, I edited my question a bit.  I'm on WordPress and the form is being generated by a plugin.  I try to avoid modifying plugin behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to limit just the Contact Us page to users from the US, this should not have a major impact on your SEO. You run into the issue of Google possibly not indexing the Contact Us page if it is not crawlable outside of the US.